# music listview is not working on 4.4 or higher?

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

This code is working fine on 4.2 and below but not on 4.4 or higher.it shows error unfortunately app has stopped working  i don't know why.please help! as I'm new to android. Isn't it because of deprecated methods ? or what ?

[This is my Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njdvj.png)

And the following is my code:

```java
package com.example.hamza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ListView lvfs;
    Cursor cursorfm;
    int count,middleperson;
    TextView tv,title;
    ContentResolver conres;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializesomestuff();
    }

    private void initializesomestuff() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lvfs=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lview);
        findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        String[] projection={MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,};
        cursorfm=conres.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,null);
        count=cursorfm.getCount();
        ////get some data
        lvfs.setAdapter(new musiclistadapter(getApplicationContext()));

    }
    /////// cutomiztion walla area///start
public class musiclistadapter extends BaseAdapter{


private Context mcontext;
String songname,songartist;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public musiclistadapter(Context applicationContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mcontext=applicationContext;
         //get the layout inflater
         mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ViewHolder holder;
        System.gc();
        tv = new TextView(mcontext.getApplicationContext());
        String id=null;
        //if(arg1==null){
         holder = new ViewHolder(); 
         arg1 = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.textviewlayout, arg2, false);
        // get all views you need to handle from the cell and save them in the view holder
         holder.itemName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
         // save the view holder on the cell view to get it back latter

            middleperson=cursorfm.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            cursorfm.moveToPosition(position);
            id=cursorfm.getString(middleperson);
            middleperson=cursorfm.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            cursorfm.moveToPosition(position);
            id=id+cursorfm.getString(middleperson);
            arg1.setTag(holder);
            holder.itemName.setText(id);
            //middleperson=cursorfm.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //id=cursorfm.getString(middleperson);
            //id+="whatever it is"+id+cursorfm.getString(middleperson);
            //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            //View row;
            //row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textviewlayout, arg2, false);
           // TextView title;
           // title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
           // title.setText(id);
            //tv.setText(id);
           // return (row);
    //  }
        //else{
            //title = (TextView) arg1;
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        //}

         //if (id != null) {
                //set the item name on the TextView
                //holder.itemName.setText(cursorfm.getString(middleperson));
           // } else {
                // make sure that when you have an if statement that alters the UI, you always have an else that sets a default value back, otherwise you will find that the recycled items will have the same UI changes
             //   holder.itemName.setText("Unknown");   
           // }

            //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
            return arg1;
        //return (title);

    }   
}
private class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemName;

}
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat trace ?!!

Comment: you are getting permission denial error , add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> for android 6.0(Marshmallow) and up you need real time permissions

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your Logtrace, you didn't provide the permission of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, as you need this permission to read media data from the device. So, you have to open the `manifest.xml` file and add the following permission before the `application` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

And about working in some devices and not working in the others, that's because the media storage location is differed across different devices and android versions, so the music media data is stored in external storage in some devices (and hence you will need the permission), and in the others not.